# One stand-point to decide if it's a "Programmers"-related question

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I found this question today
[Find a "hole" in a list of numbers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145832/find-a-hole-in-a-list-of-numbers)

For me, it's a very StackOverflow specific question. The op have a very specific task to solve and created a technique-specific-question (algorithm to find holes). The short question and hence the title. I will agree that the answers and reaction of the question is very interesting and contains a strong kind of "Programmers"-style, then it would(?) achieve in StackOverflow. Even I favorited the answer of bit comparision in between 256 integers.

Though, does it make the question more adequate to Programmers, then SO?
I would just like to bring some clearance for later judgement calls,

[Edit]
Ok I try to change the title..

Comment: Since you are kinda new, [voting on Meta is different](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences) - In this case 4 people just disagree the question is more suitable for Stack Overflow than Programmers and one agrees.

Comment: @ Yannis Thanks for clarification. I'm aware of this distinction of metas scoring system, compared to the main sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Overflow questions are typically expected to be more specific, involving particular languages, libraries, and development tools. Programmers questions tend to be more abstract - things that you would talk about around a whiteboard or when brainstorming or at a level beyond sitting at your computer writing code.

Right from [the Programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), `algorithm and data structure concepts` are on-topic. Since it's not about implementation details, it belongs here more than it does on Stack Overflow. Although answers might contain an implementation in a given programming language, that's not required in this case - a textual or pseudocode description of the algorithm would be just as good.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that the Programmers categorization, make the question a better fit here. I could probably find this more Stack Overflow in view of "give me the answer"-character, against this counter-example, which have a larger space of discussion; http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/49550/20636. I have now been helped to understand the algorithms / structures as a fairly open area of ​​Programmers.